# Move position of ggplot with coord_fixed

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I use `coord_fixed`, and my plot has different dimensions than the device I'm using to output it, it gets pushed to the middle of the space, like this:

[image]

(I added the red border afterwards to make it clear what the plot area is)

Example code is:

```
data.frame(x = seq(10), y = rnorm(10)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_col() +
  coord_fixed(1.5)
```

This is expected behavior, but I'm wondering if anyone knows how I can push the plot to take up the top size of the space instead? Like, if I want the output to look like this:
[image]

THANKS!

Comment: Two initial ideas: 1) Change output dimension to same aspect ratio. 2) Use `patchwork` / `cowplot` / `grid` to add a blank placeholder below.

Comment: `coord_fixed()` is irrelevant for what you want to do (it affects the coordinate system of the plot, not plot location); you're looking for something like `... + theme(plot.margin = margin(0, 0, 200, 0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(x = seq(10), y = rnorm(10))
plot_1 <- df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_col() +
  coord_fixed(1.5) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(colour = "red", size = 1),
    plot.margin = margin(0, 0, 100, 0, unit = "mm"))

# bottom margin
plot_1
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>